# Gitlab Mocha tests and Docker Tag problems

Tags: docker, mocha.js, gitlab

I am trying to create a correct **.gitlab-ci.yml** file. This is for the **online** gitlab.com not for a self hosted Gitlab. Most (if not all) documentation is about a self hosted gitlab instance.

What I want is to run my Mocha-Chai tests on the built container and when the tests pass I want to build an image and store it in the Gitlab Registry with a tag that matches my latest git tag.

**Test part**

I cannot get the tests running, whatever I try I always get *Mocha not found*.

Below is my *.yml* file. The build section is working.
The problem is in the test section and in the docker tag part of the release-image. I got the yml file from the official gitlab documentation [the official gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html)

```
image: docker:latest
services:
- docker:dind

stages:
- build
- test
- release
- deploy

variables:
  CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/edelacruz/cloudtrader-microservices:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/edelacruz/cloudtrader-microservices:latest

before_script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com/edelacruz/cloudtrader-microservices

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE .
    - docker push $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
    - docker run $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE npm install && npm test
```

I also tried

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
    - docker run $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE npm test
```

and

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
    - docker run $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE npm install mocha -g
    - docker run $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE npm install chai -g
    - docker run $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE npm test
```

all the the same result:

> sh: mocha: not found

the test script in *package.json* is

```
 "test": "mocha ./Test",
```

I tried both putting mocha and chai in the devDependencies and in dependencies.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.0.2",
    "mocha": "^3.4.2"
  }

 "dependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.0.2",
    "mocha": "^3.4.2"
  },
```

**Tag part**

```
variables:
  CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/edelacruz/cloudtrader-microservices:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/edelacruz/cloudtrader-microservices:latest

before_script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com/edelacruz/cloudtrader-microservices

release-image:
  stage: release
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
    - docker tag $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_TAG
    - docker push $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE
  only:
    - master
```

The release-image works if I leave out the tag part.
But I really want to have my image tagged with the git tag, not with latests or master.

> $ docker tag $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
>   $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_TAG Error parsing reference:
>   "registry.gitlab.com/edelacruz/cloudtrader-microservices:" is not a
>   valid repository/tag: invalid reference format ERROR: Job failed: exit
>   code 1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in the first approach:

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
    - docker run $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE sh -c 'npm install -g mocha && npm install && npm test'
```

I've added the globally installed mocha. What you tried in the later approaches didn't work because every `docker run` is a new container based on the image and not on the previous container.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I did put everything in my Docker image after all but this reply got me in the right direction. @stacktrace thanks for your explanation, helpful. But your answer was wrong, my base image Alpine did not have a bash shell, only the sh shell.

Comment: @EricDelaCruz:That's fine. Considering that you didn't mention what your base image was, it's hard to actually know what the "correct" answer would be. My point was you need to wrap your command in whatever shell is available so that the runner doesn't split your command in two.

Comment: @Stacktrace, yes, that was the point. I'm not sure whether `mocha` command can work without -g global install.

Comment: I think mocha can work running from the nodes_modules folder. I didn't try because I had other reasons to change the way my docker image is organized.

Answer (score 1):

In your first try (with the line `docker run $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE npm install && npm test`), the gitlab runner separates the command into `docker run $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE npm install` and `npm test`. As you may notice, the second command isn't run within a docker container.

For your second try, `docker run $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE npm test` requires that mocha be already installed in the docker image.

For your third try:

```
docker run $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE npm install mocha -g
docker run $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE npm install chai -g
docker run $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE npm test
```

Each of the commands is actually run on a separate docker container (ie. there's nothing indicating that the commands need to be run within the same docker container).

So, what's the easiest way to resolve this? Your first try is actually pretty close. You just have to make sure that the gitlab runner does not split the command into two.

Something like the following should work:

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
    - docker run $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE /bin/bash -c "npm install --only=dev; npm test"
```